# Novation Launchpad Midi Remote Script for Ableton Live

Tags: python, ableton-live

I saw in Will Marshall's Advanced APC MKii he breaks the APC grid into two 4x5 matrices, where you can move the left one, and the right one is static.

I'm trying to emulate something like this on the Launchpad.

Ultimately what I am hoping for is to create Four 2x7 matrixes (independent clip launch boxes), and nav them around by:

```
# Scene1 button + arrows = Matrix 1
# Scene2 button + arrows = Matrix 2
# Scene3 button + arrows = Matrix 3
# Scene4 button + arrows = Matrix 4
```

And the bottom row is static across all Matrices should be a stop button for that track. Ideally green when playing and press to stop, red when nothing is playing.

Ideally I'd love to be able to default code which Ableton Tracks are the defaults for each Matrix. So Matrix 1 would be Ableton Tracks 1 and 2, while Matrix 2 might default to Ableton Tracks 5 and 6.

I don't care about the scene launch buttons on the right so want to use those to drive the Arrow navigation of each matrix.

I've spent about 5 hours on this thus far and have made almost zero progress. I tried the framework tutorial http://remotescripts.blogspot.com/2010/03/introduction-to-framework-classes.html which fails / has errors - might be bc it for an old version of Live? I decompiled the existing Launchpad remote scripts and modified matrix size to see if I could just reduce to a 4x4 or 2x8 and that failed each time. I check the Log.txt and was tweaking the diff places the errors were sending me to. I tried to take code from Will's scripts and inject them into the Launchpad.py and SpecialSessionComponent.py to see if his code for the 2 sessions might help override what the Launchpad loads to. This loaded fine, didn't bomb out per the Log.txt, but it didn't override the launchpad remote scripts which loaded as usual. I also messed with Launchpad95 but that's kind of too huge.

I'm an OK python programmer. Some stuff I can code on my own, stuff like this I am a cut-paste-tweaker, and in this sense I'm making zero progress.

Questions: anyone do anything like this before? Or can anyone coach me on how to approach this?

Thanks!

note: I just posted this on the https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=229128 as well